# How to uplevel avro subfields into root field with apache pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following avro schema:

```
{
"id":1,
"subfields": {
"field_A":"value_A",
"field_B":"value_B",
"field_C":["value_C1","value_C2"]
},
other_field: "other_field"
}
```

Using Pig, I want to uplevel all the fields within "subfields" into the main level such that the resulting avro is:

```
{
"id":1,
"field_A":"value_A",
"field_B":"value_B",
"field_C":["value_C1","value_C2"]
other_field: "other_field"
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: What is the schema of the data after you load it into Pig?

Comment: Not sure, using AvroLoader() which takes it as is.

Comment: After loading it into Pig, use the `DESCRIBE` command to get the schema.